# Xml parsing issue: not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: python, xml, well-formed

**Log File:**

I'm getting the following error message and do not understand how to eliminate it:

> "C:\USERNAME\python\lib\xml\sax\handler.py", line 38, in fatalError
>   raise exception xml.sax._exceptions.SAXParseException:
>   \phase_12\dna\cog_hq_bossbot_sz.xml:6:64: not well-formed (invalid
>   token)

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scene zone="10000">
    <store_suit_point id="1" type="STREET_POINT" x="18"  y="-82" z="0.025" />
    <store_suit_point id="2" type="STREET_POINT" x="62"  y="-95" z="0.025" />
    <store_suit_point id="3" type="STREET_POINT" x="112" y="-72" z="0.025" />
    <store_suit_point id="4" type="STREET_POINT" x="128" y="-23"z="0.025" />
    <store_suit_point id="5" type="STREET_POINT" x="120" y="75" z="0.025" />
    <store_suit_point id="6" type="STREET_POINT" x="-9" y="84" z="0.025" />
    <store_suit_point id="7" type="STREET_POINT" x="-7" y="23" z="0.025" />
    <store_suit_point id="8" type="STREET_POINT" x=" 106" y="11" z=" 0.025" />
    <store_suit_point id="9" type="STREET_POINT" x="80" y="-33" z="0.025" />
    <store_suit_point id="10" type="STREET_POINT"x="56" y="-5" z="0.025" />
    <store_suit_point id="11" type="STREET_POINT" x=" 14" y="2" z="0.025" />
    <store_suit_point id="12" type="STREET_POINT" x="-23" y="-56" z="0.025" />

<group name="bossbotHQ" >
    <visgroup zone= "10000" vis="10001 10002 10003 10004 10005" >
        <suit_edge a="2" b="3" />
        <suit_edge a="3" b="4" />
        <battle_cell width="20" height="20" x="40" y="-88.5" z="0" />
    </visgroup>
    <visgroup zone="10001" vis="10001 10002 10003 10004 10005">
        <suit_edge a="4" b="5" />
        <suit_edge a="5" b="6" />
        <suit_edge a="6" b="7" />

        <battle_cell width="20" height="20" x="124" y="26" z="0" />
    </visgroup>
    <visgroup zone="10002" vis="10001 10002 10003 10004 10005">
        <suit_edge a="7" b="8" />
        <suit_edge a="8" b="9" />
        <suit_edge a="9" b="10" />
        <suit_edge a="10" b="11" />     

        <battle_cell width="20" height="20" x="49.5" y="17" z="0" />
    </visgroup>

    <visgroup zone="10003" vis="10001 10002 10003 10004 10005">
        <suit_edge a="11" b="12" />
        <suit_edge a="12" b="1" />          
        <battle_cell width="20" height="20" x="-18.5" y="-27" z="0" />
    </visgroup>
    <visgroup zone="10004" vis="10001 10002 10003 10004 10005">
        <suit_edge a="1" b="2" />
        <battle_cell width="20" height="20" x="-5" y="-71" z="0" />
    </visgroup>
</group>
</scene>
```

**Code for Parser**:

```
def createSuitPlanner(self, zone):
    sp = DistributedSuitPlannerAI(self.air, zone)
```

**Another file related to that for loading the file:**

```
def setupDNA(self):
    if self.dnaStore:
        return None
    dnaFileName = self.genDNAFileName()
    self.dnaStore = simbase.air.loadDNA(dnaFileName)
    self.dnaData = self.dnaStore.generateData()
    self.initDNAInfo()
    return None
file for the loading of the dna 
def __init__(self, loader, parentFSM, doneEvent):
    CogHQExterior.CogHQExterior.__init__(self, loader, parentFSM, doneEvent)
    **dnaFile = 'phase_12/dna/cog_hq_bossbot_sz.xml'**
```

Comment: wait i do its added in there just didnt get in there its in my source though its at the end

Comment: never mind, it just wasn't showing up in your code block. It's there...

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and post the code you are using to parse this file?

Comment: Your posted XML itself is well-formed.

Comment: i edited it matt , i hope thats enough info i dont like giving away source code but still want some help

Comment: and ofc as always i get a -1 :( i dont see whats up with this community u cant ask a darn thing without getting a -1

Comment: You don't have to give away your s3cret source code, but you have to provide code that allows us to reproduce the problem. See the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for guidance on how to write a good question.

Comment: ok im trying my best ok cause im stumped on this

Comment: Consider that the XML you've posted may not be the XML you're parsing. Try pasting what you've posted back into your file and see if it works.

Comment: hmm it is the right file weird

Comment: this is definately cog_hq_bossbot_sz.xml

Comment: so it must  be  a spacing issue ill try copying see if it works :)

Comment: @kjhughes I don't think so. Check scene -tag

Comment: @frlan:  Please mind the edit history.  The `scene` was added *after* I asserted that the posted XML was well-formed.  Furthermore, OP has since added the closing tag for `scene` (albeit with improper formatting, sigh).

Comment: improper formating ok so whats the issue now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original XML was [well-formed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085).  Your updated XML is not.

In your later-added XML's `scene` element, you are missing a space between attributes of `store_suite_point`:

```
y="-23"z="0.025"
```

should be

```
y="-23" z="0.025"
```

And again later:

```
type="STREET_POINT"x="56"
```

should be

```
type="STREET_POINT" x="56"
```

These mistakes would cause your XML to be not well-formed and must be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether these are all issues, but in terms of well formed: Your `scene`-tag is lagging closing.

Assuming `scene` is not a parent of `group`, the start of your XML should maybe look something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scene zone="10000">
    <store_suit_point id="1" type="STREET_POINT" x="18"  y="-82" z="0.025" />
    <store_suit_point id="2" type="STREET_POINT" x="62"  y="-95" z="0.025" />
    <store_suit_point id="3" type="STREET_POINT" x="112" y="-72" z="0.025" />
    <store_suit_point id="4" type="STREET_POINT" x="128" y="-23"z="0.025" />
    <store_suit_point id="5" type="STREET_POINT" x="120" y="75" z="0.025" />
    <store_suit_point id="6" type="STREET_POINT" x="-9" y="84" z="0.025" />
    <store_suit_point id="7" type="STREET_POINT" x="-7" y="23" z="0.025" />
    <store_suit_point id="8" type="STREET_POINT" x=" 106" y="11" z=" 0.025" />
    <store_suit_point id="9" type="STREET_POINT" x="80" y="-33" z="0.025" />
    <store_suit_point id="10" type="STREET_POINT"x="56" y="-5" z="0.025" />
    <store_suit_point id="11" type="STREET_POINT" x=" 14" y="2" z="0.025" />
    <store_suit_point id="12" type="STREET_POINT" x="-23" y="-56" z="0.025" />
</scene>
```

Mind the `</scene>` at the end.

Comment: meaning? close to what

Comment: so basically </scene> shouldnt be  after </group>

Comment: and it is a parent actually

Comment: oh and its at the end of the file just didnt copied in oops my bad